# Android MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission reject by Google playstore for social networking app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, permissions, google-play

I have created social networking app which also has inbuilt messaging part. So for this i need to send and receive files and need access all files (**Including PDF,APK,DOC or Raw files**) like whatsapp/telegram or other instant messaging app.

I tried to remove `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` and `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` one by one each one of them stop showing files and Media in my app's custom gallery.

When i filled `Sensitive Permission` declaration form i mentioned there that i have an chat app but didn't show them that it not limited to media files but still get rejection where whatsapp/telegram and Duo has access to `management of all files`. So how can i get `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission and what i need to tell them in form to get this permission in next update

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic You might want to focus instead on learning how to avoid the need for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, as that is mostly for apps like file managers, not social network clients or messaging apps.

Comment: @CommonsWare i just cross check her whatsapp/telegram/duo permission like. She is right these app need `Allow Management Of All Files`  . For custom gallery i think this permission is required by instant messaging app.

Comment: @androidXP: "She is right these app need Allow Management Of All Files" -- why? Why does a messaging app need the right to modify or delete all the user's files?

Comment: @CommonsWare I am not sure about that but my point is if they can get those permission they she can too. But as i know in most messaging app esply like telegram, that app can delete,create other files and folder too, that might be reason i think.

Comment: When you upload your apk in play store, they will ask for "why you need  of MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?". So explain them your requirements, what type of your application. You need to give solid reason for using MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.

Comment: @CommonsWare Without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission my app phone gallery shows blank grid in android 11. So don't you think i need that permission like other messaging apps and social networking apps?

Comment: @pratikvekariya I gave them reason which i thought is enough for getting `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` by mentioning that i have an chat app which shares files with other users.

Comment: @androidXP: "if they can get those permission they she can too" -- not necessarily. Duo is a product from Google. WhatsApp is a product from one of the world's largest companies. Telegram has been around for years. In the latter two cases, most likely the developers have dedicated Google Play account representatives. Most developers do not. And, more generally, [questions about app distribution channel policies are off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: @Ritu: "So don't you think i need that permission like other messaging apps and social networking apps?" -- I do not know you implemented your "app phone gallery". It is possible to query `MediaStore` for images without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. There are open source gallery apps, such as [LeafPic](https://github.com/apcro/leafpicrevived), that operate without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes i do have custom `bottomsheet` gallery for multiple files and media attachment. The link you shared is only managing media files so no need to ask all file management,where i need to access for apk,pdf or raw type files. 

So do you think if i mention in permission declaration form that i have custom gallery for sending and receiving files, will that help me to get that permission?

Comment: "where i need to access for apk,pdf or raw type files" -- [here is an open source file manager app](https://github.com/SimpleMobileTools/Simple-File-Manager) that does not request `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: @CommonsWare above mention app `targetSdkVersion 29.` not 30. `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` applicable from 30 not 29

Comment: @androidXP: Then perhaps the OP will need to replace the "custom bottomsheet gallery" with the Storage Access Framework. My guess is that raw paths access will be sufficient on API Level 30 for what the OP seeks, but perhaps not.

Comment: @Ritu if they understand and verify that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is necessary then they will approve app otherwise it will show error in your play console. I think they will accept your app because your app requires gallery or file manager data.

Comment: @Ritu Did you get ```Allow Management Of All File``` permission. They are rejecting my request too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you've said in your post, your app would not qualify for the `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, as explained by the [Use of all files access permission policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10467955)

> In some cases, apps may wish to access sensitive user data for purposes where a safer and more secure alternative exists, or where risk of data exposure doesn't warrant access.
>
> - Media files access (see Alternatives below)
> - Any file selection activity where the user manually selects individual files (see Alternatives below)

The same page has a list of types of apps that would qualify for `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but neither social networking, nor chat apps are included.

Telegram/WhatsApp/etc... do not (to the best of my knowledge) have `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, but rather they have:

- `targetSdkVersion=29`
- `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`
- request `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

If all three of those are true, and the app is running on Android 11+, then the permissions screen shows "Allow management of all files", because that app has access to all of those files. This is explained [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#permissions-target-any) under "Target any version":

> Users can see which apps have the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in system settings. On the **Settings > Privacy > Permission manager > Files and media** page, each app that has the permission is listed under **Allowed for all files**.

It seems likely the app would need to be updated to work without `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` before setting its `targetSdkVersion` to 30. This could be done by using the system document picker in place of your own, or following steps to allow apps that have access to that data to [share it with yours](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive).

Comment: You are right here. These apps still on API 29

Comment: If downgrade the targets API level 29, then on uploading bundle on play store giving error:- "Your app currently targets API level 29 and must target at least API level 30 to ensure that it is built on the latest APIs optimised for security and performance. Change your app's target API level to at least 30."

Comment: what is the solution for this all other apps are using this permission, why can't I?