# Playstore reject my MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: flutter, permissions, google-play-services

I have created an app where i save images to device directory from flutter app

And when i try to.upload this app on playstore it gave me this permission error.This permission is must for Android 10 and above so if a remove it my files didn't save. Any solution please?

Google send me this mail regarding to the permission

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362259/android-manage-external-storage-permission-reject-by-google-playstore-for-social?rq=2 .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android MANAGE\_EXTERNAL\_STORAGE permission reject by Google playstore for social networking app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68362259/android-manage-external-storage-permission-reject-by-google-playstore-for-social)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.